# How can I configure npm to use Windows-style line endings in package.json?

Tags: npm, line-endings

I run Windows, and when npm modifies my package.json file, it writes it using Unix-style line endings (<kbd>LF</kbd>). I want it to use Windows-style line endings (<kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>).

Is there a global config setting, or even a command-line option to make npm use the correct EOL characters?

Comment: I do not think line endings can be changed by NPM config or cli options. But if you are using git at the same time, I suggest turn on auto-convert by `git config core.autocrlf true`. Then when you run `git add`, the line endings are converted automatically and will not result in an extra commit.

Answer (score 14):

**Update:** The even easier fix is to use [npm@5.8.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.8.0) or newer.

Assuming Git, the easiest "solution" to this problem is to use a `.gitattributes` file to specify that `package.json` (and now `package-lock.json`) should always use LF:

```
# .gitattributes in project root
package.json text eol=lf
package-lock.json text eol=lf
```

Comment: Awesome.  Note you can also use a wildcard: `package*.json text eol=lf`

Comment: I debated using the wildcard... but what if a project includes some other file that starts with `package` and ends with `.json`?! (Premature optimization is fun.)